# How to left-pad an integer with spaces?

Tags: java, formatting, int

How to format an Integer value without leading zero? I tried using decimal format but I can't achieve exact result:

```
DecimalFormat dFormat=new DecimalFormat("000");

mTotalNoCallsLbl.setText(""+dFormat.format(mTotalNoOfCallsCount));
mTotalNoOfSmsLbl.setText(""+dFormat.format(mTotalNoOfSmsCount));
mSelectedNoOfCallsLbl.setText(""+dFormat.format(mSelectedNoOfCallLogsCount));
mSelectedNoOfSmsLbl.setText(""+dFormat.format(mSelectedNoOfSmsCount));
```

I'm getting these output :

```
500
004
011
234
```

but I want these:

```
500
  4
 11
234
```

My question is how to replace the zeroes with spaces?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you want to left-pad with spaces, so perhaps you want:

```
String.format("%3d", yourInteger);
```

For example:

```
int[] values = { 500, 4, 11, 234 };

for (int v : values) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%3d", v));
}
```

Output:

```
500
  4
 11
234
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. already i tried this way.. but formatting is not happen.... display the number right to left order

Comment: @Karthick You tried using `String.format`? Or are you referring to my answer before the last edit.

Comment: no first i tired String.format only.. after that i moved into decimalformat..... thanks for your reply