# A dice game between two players. The player who gets 21 first wins

Tags: java

There is a game between two players, and the first player who gets 21 points wins. 
when both players reach 21 on the same number of rolls, there is a tie.

The points are added up as the dices are rolled.

The format of this should be done as follows.

*** GAME 1 ***

```
 Roll              Player 1         Player 2

1               5                 4

2               7                 10

3               12                14

4               13                16

5               19                21
  player 2 wins!
```

The code below is what I've tried so far.

I'm stuck because I have no idea how to create a chart like the one above.

If I try to make the chart inside the while loop, it will repeatedly make the chart.

If I try to make the chart outside the while loop, which is after the while loop, it will

execute only when one of the players reach points 21.

Can anyone help me out how to make this code?

```
 import java.util.*;


public class Dice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random rand = new Random();

  System.out.println("How many games do you want to play?");
  int games= input.nextInt();

  System.out.println(" *** Game 1 *** ");
  int sum1=0;
  int sum2=0;
  while (sum1!=21&&sum2!=21){
     int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
     int roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

     sum1=+roll1;
     sum2=+roll2;
  }

  if(sum1>sum2){

     System.out.println("player 1 wins");
  }

  else if(sum1<sum2){
     System.out.println("player 2 wins");
     }

   }

}
```

Comment: I want the program to run until someone wins, and print a chart like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problem

1. you want to test that `sum1` and `sum2` are less than 21 **not** `!=`
2. you should use `+=` not `=+`
3. Introduced a counter for the rolls

**Note** 
I think you logic is not correct, though as what should happen if **both** get to `21` on the same throw?

```
    System.out.println(" *** Game 1 *** ");
    int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    int rollNumber = 1;
    System.out.println("Roll\tPlayer 1\tPlayer 2");
    while (sum1 < 21 && sum2 < 21){
         int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
         int roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

         sum1 += roll1;
         sum2 += roll2;

         if (sum1 > 21) sum1 = 21;
         if (sum2 > 21) sum2 = 21;

         System.out.format("%d\t%d\t%d%n", rollNumber++, sum1, sum2);
    }

    if(sum1>sum2){

         System.out.println("player 1 wins");
    }
    else if(sum1<sum2){
         System.out.println("player 2 wins");
    }

    }
```

**output**

```
 *** Game 1 *** 
Roll    Player 1    Player 2
1   5   4
2   4   5
3   2   3
4   3   1
5   3   3
6   2   3
7   5   6
player 2 wins
```

Comment: why doesn't != work?     since the numbers are adding up and as soon as the numbers add up to 21 they break out of the while loop, isn't it ok to use !=?

Comment: And shouldn't it be System.out.format ("%d\t%d\t%d%n", rollNumber++, sum1, sum2);                                                                                                                                   I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Because `18 + 6 == 24`   There is no guarantee that the count will ever be exactly `21` and it will loop forever

Comment: oh you're right I get it

Comment: changed the output to `sum1 sum2`

Comment: If I run your code, I get numbers that are higher than 21 for the last number in the chart.

Comment: Also, if there's a tie, (21:21) is the code still valid if I just put in another if statement?

Comment: in your code, if sum1 is like 19, and the random number is like 3, it prints 22 for the last number. How do we make the code not to accept the last number?

Comment: *put in another if statement* Yes, I think it needs this.

Comment: Before printing out you can test if the `sum1` or `sum2` is greater than `21` and if so set `sum1 = 21;`  Done the edit in the code

Comment: In case of testing if they are bigger than 21, should I put that testing statement right before  System.out.format("%d\t%d\t%d%n", rollNumber++, sum1, sum2);?

Comment: I have modified my code

Comment: I really appreciate Scary Wombat. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, do you how to space the numbers out?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989541/how-to-left-pad-an-integer-with-spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you want a printout each turn, you need to print inside the while loop. Here would be an example snippet that has such a feature. Of course, this isn't a complete program, and could use some formatting love.

```
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
int round = 1;
while(sum1 < 21 && sum2 < 21) { // not sure if you noticed this bug in your code..
    sum1 += rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sum2 += rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    System.out.println("Round " + round + " " + sum1 + " " + sum2);
    round++;
}
```